# Regex for all characters upto not including \n

Tags: regex

Here I have a text string.

```
Serial#......... 12345678910123456\nCust#........... 654321\nCustomer Name... Some Customer\nBILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 123456 - Some Company Pty Ltd\nDATE...... 01/01/00
```

I want to capture 2 parts of this string.

```
Cust#........... 654321 BILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 123456 - Some Company Pty Ltd
```

using regex.

So far I have `Cust#.*?\d+` which captures

```
Cust#........... 654321
```

However I dont think this is the best approach.

*Note*.. This is 1 string from thousands, so data within strings is dynamic, can I capture what is within end of line `\n` character to achieve my result??

Comment: What language are you using? Better to split on `\n` and just take the items you need from the resulting array.

Comment: using python for this project. i want to use regex as I would like to group `Cust#........... 654321 BILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 123456 - Some Company Pty Ltd` for later on the script

Comment: There's a story (of a kind) going "I have a problem. I solved it with regular expressions. Now I have *two* problems." A regex can be a very powerful tool, *for the right job*, but it's not a universal tool that will solve any and all problems. For your case, especially using Python, why not use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split (on the newline) into a list, and then get the two elements you need and concatenate into a new string?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex: `^.*?\n(.*?)\n.*?\n(.*?)\n.*$` at least it should give you a different way of looking at the problem.

It describes the entire string, using carriage returns as element delimiters.  The parenthesis defines groups which you want to save, which are the 2nd and 4th groups.

Of course this depends on the elements you want always being the 2nd and 4th and being delimited by the newlines.

https://regex101.com/r/harmzn/1

Answer (score 0):

You might use 2 capturing groups. In the first group, use your pattern without the lazy quantifier, as the digits are at the end of the line.

Then match (not capture) all the lines that do not start with `BILL`

After that, capture in group 2 the whole line that starts with `BILL`

```
^(Cust#.*\d+)(?:\r?\n(?!BILL ).*)*\r?\n(BILL .*)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `Cust#.*\d+` The pattern to match Cust# with the digits at the end
- `)` Close group
- `(?:\r?\n(?!BILL ).*)*\r?\n` Match all lines that do not start with `BILL`
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `BILL .*` Match the line that starts with `BILL`
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hBF85Z/1)